Go обгоняет C на задаче с объёмным выводом
Задача состоит в выводе последовательностей вида: 000 001 002 ... 997 998 999.
Go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)

    buffer := bufio.NewWriterSize(os.Stdout, 64 * 1024)

    b := make([]byte, n+1)
    b[n] = '\n'

    var search func(i int)
    search = func(i int) {
        if i == n {
            buffer.Write(b)
        } else {
            for d := '0'; d <= '9'; d++ {
                b[i] = byte(d)
                search(i + 1)
            }
        }
    }
    search(0);
    buffer.Flush()
}

C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BSIZE (64 * 1024)

void search(char b[], int n, int i) {
    if (i == n) {
        fwrite(b, 1, n + 1, stdout);
    } else {
        for (char d = '0'; d <= '9'; ++d) {
            b[i] = d;
            search(b, n, i + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char *buf = malloc(BSIZE);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, BSIZE) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    char *b = malloc((size_t)n + 1);
    if (b == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    b[n] = '\n';
    search(b, n, 0);
}

Сборка и проверка:

$ gcc -O3 temp.c 

$ time diff <(echo 8 | go run temp.go) <(echo 8 | ./a.out)

real  0m4.043s
user  0m3.816s
sys   0m1.100s


Сравнение времён. На ста миллионах C отстаёт на полсекунды:

$ time echo 8 | go run temp.go | wc -l
100000000

real  0m1.641s
user  0m2.396s
sys   0m0.216s

$ time echo 8 | ./a.out | wc -l
100000000

real  0m2.120s
user  0m2.932s
sys   0m0.172s


На миллиарде C отстаёт на почти шесть секунд:

$ time echo 9 | go run temp.go | wc -l
1000000000

real  0m16.166s
user  0m24.524s
sys   0m2.352s

$ time echo 9 | ./a.out | wc -l
1000000000

real  0m22.044s
user  0m30.720s
sys   0m2.424s


Я иногда использую код на С в качестве эталона в задачах, чтобы понять сколько времени уходит на вычисления, сколько на вывод. Но тут эталон сломался. Что я делаю не так?
P.S. Вычисления не тормозят: если в обоих вариантах удвоить вывод, разница во времени почти удвоится. Это именно вывод.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

¿В вопросе намеренно представлен лексически схожий, но семантически различный код на разных языках? Хотите сравнить производительность именно языков - извольте написать код, где бы в го было реализовано поведение потоков ввода/вывода из С, либо наоборот, в С было реализован буферизированный вывод, как в го.

@user7860670 вывод в C разумеется тоже буферизированный

Если так подумать, то го скорее всего тянет не сишную stdout, а обращается к системным вызовам, вот и разница. Попробуйте переписать код под системный дескриптор stdout.

@evo но это не объясняет что не так с сишным stdout

@andreymal "тоже буферизированный" - я писал не про то, что он не буфферезированный, а про то, что "буферизированный" писатель в го и "буферизированный" поток в С - две большие разницы и странно их сравнивать напрямую.

@user7860670 почему?

@andreymal Что почему? Почему они разные или почему сравнивая их некорректно говорить о разнице между языками?

@user7860670 всё сразу

@andreymal Почему они разные - это вопрос скорее к тем, кто писал библиотеку на го. Они явно не хотели заморачиться, реализуя что-то потоко-подобное, как в С. А разница между между библиотечными функциями, далающими разные вещи, мало говорит о разнице между языками. Как я уже писал выше: Хотите сравнить производительность именно языков - извольте написать код, где бы в го было реализовано поведение потоков ввода/вывода из С, либо наоборот, в С было реализован буферизированный вывод, как в го. Иначе в лучшем случае получается сравнение именно разных библиотечных процедур.

@user7860670 опять воды какой-то налили, так ничего и не объяснив

@andreymal Я вам все развернуто расписал по каждому пункту.

@user7860670 нет, вы ограничились абсолютно абстрактными «вопрос скорее к тем» и «функциями, делающими разные вещи», которые объясняют ровно ничего

@andreymal А что вы еще хотите от меня услышать? Я не знаком детально с историей развития языка го и не знаю, какие именно соображения привели к нынешней реализации пакета bufio и не факт, что сейчас это вообще еще возможно выяснить. Важно только то, что они не стали делать по образцу сишных потоков.

@user7860670 «А что вы еще хотите от меня услышать?» — ответ на вопрос «почему». То, что разница вызвана отличиями в реализациях стандартных библиотек, мы выяснили ещё вчера в чате, который вы принципиально игнорируете. Собственно, я уже написал код на C, который быстрее чем Go и даже Rust, но ответа на вопрос «почему» это всё равно не даёт

@andreymal Тогда снова читайте мой предыдущий комментарий. Хотите покопать - вперед, пишите разработчикм го, может они что-то пояснят про свой подход при создании bufio.

@user7860670 почему не «пишите разработчикам glibc»?

@andreymal ¿А зачем писать разработчикам glibc? Это же не они придумали итерфейс для работы с FILE.

@user7860670 и что в этом интерфейсе такого особенного, что мешает ему быть по производительности на уровне Go или Rust?

@andreymal c ходу можно назвать три пункта: 1) в го чисто писатель, а работа с FILE * предполагает перемежающиеся операции чтения и записи 2) в го нет никакой синхронизации, а реализация работы с FILE * обязана неявно производить синхронизацию 3) в го записывается кусок массива байт, а в С записывается отдельные байты каждого из уложенных в массив объектов

@user7860670, 1) stdout не предполагает чтения из него, а операции ниже уровнем одинаковы для C и Go 2) в Go записью в файл ведает отдельный поток (моя гипотеза после разглядывания strace), а вот работу с FILE можно сделать без синхронизации (так было в MSVC - там есть или был single threaded runtime library, как сделано в GCC пока не знаю). 3) C как и Go пишет байты блоками, на интерфейс fwrite можно не смотреть, он такой из эпохи 16-битных систем.

@user7860670 синхронизация естественно есть везде (но в Go слегка специфическая из-за асинхронщины), а про байты что мешает сделать в C как в Go?

@StanislavVolodarskiy 1) Вот в этом и проблема, stdout не предполагает чтения из него, а работа с FILE должна организовываться так, как будто чтение возможно - лишние сложности. 2) В го может запись и ведет отдельный поток, однако сам bufio этого вроде как не требует, а работа с FILE в актуальных версиях стандарта С требует синхронизации 3) а я вот как раз предлагаю смотреть на интерфейс fwrite, так как он явно не  способствует эффективной записи простого массива байт.

@andreymal В го ее нет, BufferedWriter даже явно отмечен "This type is not thread safe.". Сделать в С как в го ничего наверное не машает, но уже позно что-то менять и есть fwrite.

@user7860670 та реализация буфера, которую я сам написал на C, работает поверх тех же самых FILE и fwrite — и при этом является самой быстрой. Из этого следует, что смотреть на fwrite не надо

@StanislavVolodarskiy Специально заглянул в стандарт (n3220). Блокировка не просто должна быть, а еще и reentrant: 7.23.2 Streams "7 Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time."

@andreymal То, что оно работает поверх тех же самых FILE и fwrite  скорее говорит о том, что это еще не самая быстрая реализация )

А если почитать про fwrite, "2 The fwrite function writes, from the array pointed to by ptr, up to nmemb elements whose size is specified by size, to the stream pointed to by stream. For each object, size calls are made to the fputc function, taking the values (in order) from an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object.", то получается, что при длине строки 8 при каждом fwrite должно производиться не менее 10 блокировок. Чет вообще жесть.

@user7860670 в исходниках и glibc, и musl я вижу ровно одну блокировку и тупое перемножение size и nmemb, что создаёт у меня подозрение, что это какая-то устаревшая чушь

@andreymal "подозрение, что это какая-то устаревшая чушь" - я же привел источник - n3220, то бишь январь этого года. "в исходниках и glibc, и musl я вижу ровно одну блокировку и тупое перемножение size и nmemb" - а у меня это создает подозрение, что 1) библиотеки не соответствуют стандарту 2) это несоответствие намеренно допущено в угоду эффективности Без такого срезания углов отставание С в тесте наверняка было бы заметно больше.

@user7860670, а для вас это открытие, то что одни люди пишут код, а доугие (потом уже) изобретают стандарты? И частенько усилия стандартизаторов совсем не нравятся писателям кода

Сдаётся мне, что фальстарт. Что если замерить время не всей трубы из трёх процессов и максимально убрать системную часть, а время конкретного процесса: echo 9 | time go run temp.go > /dev/null или echo 9 > /tmp/9 ; time go run temp.go < /tmp/9 > /dev/null, то Go, на этом тесте, обыграет C в разы.

В го оптимизация на оптимизации. Сравнив "strace -f go run" и "strace a.out" всё объяснит. Да, быстрее, но какими методами? strace: 13000 строк от ./a.out и 65000 строк от go run. Буферизация и вывод созданы через futex'ы и многопоточность. В Вашем примере на С ничего подобного нет. Сравнивать смысла нет. Весь спор и 45629867 комментариев непонятно к чему. В этом вроде и есть смысл Go - "одно решение для каждой проблемы" (решения оптимизированы по "я**а", не обращая внимания на затраты ресурсов, любой ценой). Ваш пример на С одно из N решений.

@nx4n, не понял против чего вы возражаете. Оба решения стандартны для своих языков. Именно поэтому их имеет смысл сравнивать. Нормальные программисты на C и на Go их напишут. И возникнет вопрос: почему решение на высокоуровневом Go обходит таковое на низкоуровневом C? По логике должно быть наоборот: удобно программировать, но за это платишь. Но тут не так.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, не понял где вы тут увидели "низкоуровневый С". И я не возражаю.

В ответе вариант с ускорением задачи только на Си (go и Rust на комп не ставил)).
Наверное для достижения высокой скорости придется самому писать низкоуровневые вещи, "затачивая" их под конкретную задачу.
По сути, тут мы хотим иметь буферизованный вывод, желательно приближенный к привычному сишному stdio.
Я попробовал заменить FILE *stdout на простой поток вывода с буферизаций O_File (код реализации см. ниже) и получил на данной задаче почти двукратное ускорение.
Потребовались минимальные изменения кода автора:

вызов fwrite(b, 1, n + 1, stdout); был заменен на f_write(out, b, n + 1);
добавлен один параметр в функцию search -- void search(O_File *out, char b[], int n, int i), соответствующие корректировки внесены в вызовы search;
в коде main создаем поток O_File out = f_init_w(1, buf, BSIZE);, связанный с открытым файловым дескриптором стандартного вывода и в конце main явно вызывается функция выталкивания буфера потока вывода f_flush(&out);

Для начала, результаты:
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc -DHAND_BUF_OUT f_write.c -O3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time echo 8 | ./a.out | wc -l
100000000

real    0m0.819s
user    0m1.175s
sys 0m0.232s
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc  f_write.c -O3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time echo 8 | ./a.out | wc -l
100000000

real    0m1.408s
user    0m2.008s
sys 0m0.238s
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc -DHAND_BUF_OUT f_write.c -O3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time echo 9 | ./a.out | wc -l
1000000000

real    0m7.587s
user    0m11.552s
sys 0m2.537s
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc  f_write.c -O3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ time echo 9 | ./a.out | wc -l
1000000000

real    0m14.376s
user    0m20.820s
sys 0m2.725s
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ 

А вот сорсы (ветка #ifdef HAND_BUF_OUT реализация с "ручной буферизацией", другая ветка -- код из вопроса; размер буфера одинаковы в обеих ветках):
#ifdef HAND_BUF_OUT

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct O_File {
  int fd,
    flags;
  char *buf;
  size_t b_size,
    pos;
} O_File;


O_File
f_init_w (int fd, char *buf, size_t b_size)
{
  struct O_File f = {.fd = fd, .buf = buf, .b_size = b_size};

  return f;
}

ssize_t
i_write (int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
  ssize_t r = 0;
  
  while (count) {
    ssize_t l = write(fd, buf, count);

    if (l == count)
      return r + count;
    if (l < 0)
      return l;

    buf += l;
    r += l;
    count -= l;
  }

  return r;
}

ssize_t
f_flush (O_File *f)
{
  if (f->flags == EOF)
    return EOF;
  
  ssize_t r = i_write(f->fd, f->buf, f->pos);
  if (r < 0)
    f->flags = EOF;

  f->pos = 0;
  return r;
}

ssize_t
f_write (O_File *f, void *buf, size_t count)
{
  ssize_t ret = count;

  if (f->pos + count <= f->b_size) {
    memcpy(f->buf + f->pos, buf, count);
    f->pos += count;
  } else {
    ssize_t r = f_flush(f);
    if (r < 0)
      return r;

    if (count > f->b_size) {
      if ((r = i_write(f->fd, buf, count)) < 0) {
        f->flags = EOF;
        return r;
      }
    } else {
      memcpy(f->buf, buf, count);
      f->pos += count;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}


void search(O_File *out, char b[], int n, int i) {
    if (i == n) {
      f_write(out, b, n + 1);
    } else {
      for (char d = '0'; d <= '9'; ++d) {
        b[i] = d;
        search(out, b, n, i + 1);
      }
    }
}

#define BSIZE (64 * 1024)

int main() {
    char *buf = malloc(BSIZE);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    O_File out = f_init_w(1, buf, BSIZE);
    /*    
    if (setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, BSIZE) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    */
    
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    char *b = malloc((size_t)n + 1);
    if (b == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    b[n] = '\n';
    search(&out, b, n, 0);

    f_flush(&out);
}


#else

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BSIZE (64 * 1024)

void search(char b[], int n, int i) {
    if (i == n) {
        fwrite(b, 1, n + 1, stdout);
    } else {
        for (char d = '0'; d <= '9'; ++d) {
            b[i] = d;
            search(b, n, i + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char *buf = malloc(BSIZE);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, BSIZE) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    char *b = malloc((size_t)n + 1);
    if (b == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    b[n] = '\n';
    search(b, n, 0);
}

#endif

P.S.
Если найдутся желающие развить этот набросок до stdio -- welcome.
P.P.S.
Выводы я делать не хочу, предлагаю каждому подумать самому над состоянием индустрии...

Отличный пример. Жаль, что Вы измеряли время всей трубы, т.к. wc -l существенно тормозит. Если измерить отдельно a.out > file, то ваше ускорение 3.5...5 раз в зависимости от системы. И это на 30...80% шустрее, чем GO или использование fwrite_unlocked() (на 90%).

@Serge3leo, спасибо за информацию. Просто у меня нет GO, поэтому реально мог сравнить только с теми  измерениями Си, что приведены в тексте вопроса

Это не ответ, а развёрнутый комментарий.
Я сделал пример бенчмарка, который выводит в файл 10 тысяч раз первый абзац Lorem Ipsum
Также там есть ваш пример
Ваш пример действительно демонстрирует большую разницу в скорости выполнения: 5 секунд Си против 1.6 секунд Го.
НО! бенчмарк с чистым выводом такое не показывает.
И Си, Го в бенчмарке действуют одинаково: открывают файл, пишут в него строки, закрывают файл.
Пример для Си:
package c_out

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* file = NULL;
int PrepareOut() {
    file = fopen("c_out.txt", "w+b");
    return (file != NULL);
}

void CleanUp() {
    fclose(file);
}

const char LoremIpsum[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n";

void Run(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fputs(LoremIpsum, file);
    }
    fflush(file);
}

*/
import "C"

func Prepare() bool {
    return C.PrepareOut() != 0
}

func Run(n int) {
    C.Run(C.int(n))
}

func CleanUp() {
    C.CleanUp()
}

Пример для Go
package go_out

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

var file *os.File

func Prepare() bool {
    f, err := os.Create("go_out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    file = f
    return true
}

func CleanUp() {
    file.Close()
}

const LoremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n"

func Run(n int) {
    out := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        out.WriteString(LoremIpsum)
    }
    out.Flush()
}

Результат бенчмарка:
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: some/bench
cpu: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1260P
BenchmarkGoout-16              8         153202019 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-16               6         184548701 ns/op               2 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      some/bench      2.668s

Вроде бы Го обгоняет?
Но запустим ещё несколько раз
BenchmarkGoout-16              7         155197764 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-16               8         137439268 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-16              9         151046499 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-16               8         173827842 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-16              8         143111627 ns/op            4218 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-16               8         137793313 ns/op               2 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-16              8         158575604 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-16               8         169162607 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op


Видно, что результаты сравнимые. Поэтому я бы не стал говорить, что Go обгоняет Си на задаче с объемным выводом.
ВДОГОНКУ
Данные выше получены в WSL на виндовой партиции. Это, конечно, вносит долю неопределённости в результаты.
Для чистоты эксперимента прогнал на чисто линуксовой машине:
go test -benchmem -bench 'BenchmarkGoout|BenchmarkCOut' -benchtime=20x ./bench
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: some/bench
cpu: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
BenchmarkGoout-32             20          14473849 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-32              20          18762605 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-32             20          15798282 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-32              20          19778202 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-32             20          15402149 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-32              20          19993675 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-32             20          15215966 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-32              20          19658964 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

BenchmarkGoout-32             20          15823734 ns/op            4216 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkCOut-32              20          20650712 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op

Го стабильно обгоняет на 30%.
ВДОГОНКУ2
Прогнал тесты в образе на базе Alpine Linux
С приложением ситуация аналогична: разница в производительности в три раза.
/bin/bash -c 'time echo 8 | ./go_app | wc -l'
100000000

real    0m0.609s
user    0m0.675s
sys     0m0.112s
/bin/bash -c 'time echo 8 | ./c_app | wc -l'
100000000

real    0m1.694s
user    0m1.800s
sys     0m0.344s

Бенчмарк для Го:
bench-1  | goos: linux
bench-1  | goarch: amd64
bench-1  | pkg: some/bench
bench-1  | cpu: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900
bench-1  | BenchmarkGoToFile-24                       20           9211943 ns/op           65656 B/op          4 allocs/op
bench-1  | BenchmarkC_ToFile-24                       20           9816959 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
bench-1  | BenchmarkGoToDevFile-24                    20          37064680 ns/op           65656 B/op          4 allocs/op
bench-1  | BenchmarkC_ToDevFile-24                    20          36987889 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
bench-1  | BenchmarkGoToStdStream-24                  20          36894987 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
bench-1  | BenchmarkC_ToStdStream-24                  20          36866660 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
bench-1  | PASS
bench-1  | ok   some/bench      3.501s


Вы пишете в файл. Возможно, вы измеряете производительность вашего диска.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Оба бенчмарка пишут в файл. Поэтому накладные на создание файл, синхронизацию файловой системы и закрытие файла должны быть одинаковы (имхо). Данные в ответе я получил на WSL, поэтому для чистоты эксперимента погонял на чисто линуксовой машине, и там Го стабильно обгоняет на 30%, но не в разы.

Про разы нет разговора. Разговор про то что C - низкоуровневный язык, хорошо использующий ресурсы системы. Почему он на некоторых задачах отстаёт от Go? Я не утверждаю что это так на всех задачах с объёмным выводом. Только на некоторых. Вы привели другую задачу, в других условиях. Но это не поможет мне понять что не так с моей задачей.

@StanislavVolodarskiy хм... Похоже, в glibc и в Го по-разному устроены стандартные потоки. Я заменил в бенчмарке вывод на stderr для Си и на os.Stderr для Го, и получил разницу в 4.5 раз: Го выводит 10 тысяч строк за 1.7 миллисекунды, а Си за 8.1 миллисекунду.

В ваших тестах C сбрасывает буфер выходного потока когда встречает '\n' в тексте (он есть в конце вашего текста). Это строчная буферизация. В Go буферизация не строчная. Чтобы поставить оба кода в равные условия, я использовал setvbuf. Это стандартный приём увеличения производительности на С если программа много печатает и не предназначена для интерактивного ввода от пользователя.

@StanislavVolodarskiy реально проблема в стандартном потоке вывода. Когда я явным образом открыл /dev/stderr для вывода, то Си-шный бенчмарк стал выполняться наравне с Го-шником.

Программа однопоточная, стало быть синхронизацию доступа к stdout можно упростить.
Если, скажем, в начале main() добавить строки:
    #ifdef FLOCKFILE
        flockfile(stdout);
    #endif

То производительно вывода повысится. К примеру, на macOS 14.7 (Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz), выигрыш около 25%.
Тестовый запуск немного видоизменён для улучшения стабильности, что бы не учитывать wc -l и прочего.
$ gcc-mp-14 -O3 temp2.c
$ echo 8 | time ./a.out > out
        4,86 real         4,61 user         0,22 sys
$ gcc-mp-14 -O3 -DFLOCKFILE temp2.c
$ echo 8 | time ./a.out > out
        3,61 real         3,39 user         0,21 sys

P.S.
Во FreeBSD/Linux есть функция fwrite_unlocked(), а для Windows _fwrite_nolock(), которые, хотя и нестандартны, но более эффективны, чем предварительный захват stdout.
P.P.S.
Впрочем, для macOS, iOS и др. fwrite_unlocked() несложно реализовать на основе стандартной putc_unlocked().

NB Поставьте плюсик ответу avp. Я пересказываю его идею, только используя стандартный C.
С оказывается медленнее Go из-за особенностей стандартной библиотеки.
В C

буфер для файла встроен в сам файл;
функция fwrite по стандарту обязана работать в многопоточной среде.

Чтобы не допускать гонку fwrite использует блокировку (пример исходного кода). Если вызвать её миллиард раз, она миллиард раз блокирует файл, что требует времени.
В Go

буфер – отдельный объект;
буфер не обязан работать в многопоточной среде.

Вызов buffer.Write ничего не блокирует, только переписывает данные в буфер. Когда буфер заполняется, он выполняет запись в файл и эта запись синхронная, то есть какая-то блокировка есть. Но в случае с C блокировка вызывается каждые десять байт (это длина одной строки), а в случае с Go – каждые 64KB, то есть в шесть с половиной тысяч раз реже. Что и позволяет Go обойти C.
Чтобы подтвердить теорию практикой, я написал для C буфер. Это полностью стандартный C, данные по-прежнему записываются вызовами fwrite, но эти вызовы пишут каждый по 64KB данных за раз.
Сама программа мало изменилась:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <buffer_t.h>

#define BSIZE (64 * 1024)

static buffer_t bufout;

static void search(char b[/* n + 1 */], int n, int i) {
    if (i == n) {
        bwrite(&bufout, (size_t)n + 1, b);
    } else {
        for (char d = '0'; d <= '9'; ++d) {
            b[i] = d;
            search(b, n, i + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    if (!binit(&bufout, BSIZE, stdout)) {
        return 1;
    }

    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    char *b = malloc((size_t)n + 1);
    if (b == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    b[n] = '\n';
    search(b, n, 0);

    bflush(&bufout);
    bterm(&bufout);
}

Заголовочный файл буфера:
#ifndef BUFFER_T_H_
#define BUFFER_T_H_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t pos;
    unsigned char *data;
    FILE *file;
} buffer_t;

bool binit(buffer_t *buffer, size_t size, FILE *file);
void bterm(buffer_t *buffer);
bool bflush(buffer_t *buffer);
bool bwrite(buffer_t *buffer, size_t size, void *data);

#endif

Реализация буфера:
#include <buffer_t.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool binit(buffer_t *buffer, size_t size, FILE *file) {
    unsigned char *data = malloc(size);
    if (data == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->pos = 0;
    buffer->data = data;
    buffer->file = file;
    return true;
}

void bterm(buffer_t *buffer) {
    free(buffer->data);
    buffer->file = NULL;
    buffer->data = NULL;
    buffer->pos = 0;
    buffer->size = 0;
}

bool bflush(buffer_t *buffer) {
    size_t written = fwrite(buffer->data, 1, buffer->pos, buffer->file);
    if (written < buffer->pos) {
        return false;
    }
    buffer->pos = 0;
    fflush(buffer->file);
    return true;
}

bool bwrite(buffer_t *buffer, size_t size, void *data) {
    while (size > 0) {
        size_t space = buffer->size - buffer->pos;
        if (size <= space) {
            memcpy(buffer->data + buffer->pos, data, size);
            buffer->pos += size;
            return true;
        }
        if (buffer->pos == 0) {
            return fwrite(data, 1, size, buffer->file) == size;
        }
        memcpy(buffer->data + buffer->pos, data, space);
        buffer->pos += space;
        size -= space;
        data = (unsigned char *)data + space;
        if (!bflush(buffer)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

Для обоих тестов C с буфером на четверть обгоняет Go. Статус кво восстановлен:

$ time echo 8 | ./standard-c | wc -l
100000000

real  0m2.165s
user  0m2.964s
sys   0m0.208s

$ time echo 8 | ./buffered-c | wc -l
100000000

real  0m1.025s
user  0m1.560s
sys   0m0.312s

$ time echo 8 | ./standard-go | wc -l
100000000

real  0m1.453s
user  0m2.108s
sys   0m0.204s

$ time echo 9 | ./standard-c | wc -l
1000000000

real  0m21.429s
user  0m29.052s
sys   0m2.624s

$ time echo 9 | ./buffered-c | wc -l
1000000000

real  0m11.316s
user  0m17.980s
sys   0m3.492s

$ time echo 9 | ./standard-go | wc -l
1000000000

real  0m15.540s
user  0m23.400s
sys   0m2.296s


P.S. Код лежит в репозитории c-go-stdout-performance. Убедитесь сами.

А зачем делать окончательный вывод через fwrite? Неужели из-за мультитредной блокировки?  Если ее отбросить, то можно использовать дескриптор, связанный с уже открытым файлом (скажем, stdout) и вывод делать прямо вызовом write. В этом случае в  binit() нужно запомнить в структуре fileno(file)

@avp, я хотел написать ответ на стандартном C. Когда есть буфер fwrite и write не отличаются по скорости. А переносимость для меня важна, я сам задавал вопрос про стандартные возможности языков.

Интересно с производительностью. Т.е. получается (сорсы я не смотрел), что если мы пишем через fwrite больше, чем буфер этого FILE, то напрямую (без перезаписи в буфер) вызывается write? Вообще, почему бы и нет  (я в своей реализации простого буферизованного потока в этой теме именно так и написал код)

Rust всего на 1% медленнее чем buffered-c

@avp, сорсы очень путанные, но, кажется, прямой записи нет. Ещё загадочный факт: когда я в решении с буфером выключаю буферизацию самого файла (что должно привести к росту производительности, буфер на буфере всё только замедляет) производительность падает.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, да, жаль что время KISS решений ушло из большого софта, а время чтобы серьезно покопаться в GNU FILEs я вряд ли найду
